# find a string in a file

Tags: bash, shell, unix, grep

I have a file of form
foo.txt

```
  id, some_string, stringy_string.. 
  and so on
```

How do I find a particular id in this foo.txt

This id will/should be present in just one line. (i.e no multiple instances?)
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on how the id's look like. If they do not contain any grep special characters, you can use

```
grep '^id,' foo.txt
```

The `^` matches the beginning of the line, the comma just makes sure the id ends there (so `id12` is not matched in `id123`).

You have to escape special characters if they can appear in the id.

Answer (score 4):

`sed -n '/id/p' filename`
it will display that particular pattern (id)
and
`grep -o -n 'id' filename`
it will display that id and also line number of the pattern matches in that file.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep "id" filename
```

You can easily search an id or string or anything from a file.

If you want to replace the string to another string,

you can use sed:

```
sed 's/your string/new string/g'
```